# Which command can number lines starting from 0?

Tags: bash

I need to number lines starting from from 0.

How I can do it? I tried `cat -b`, but it starts from 1.

I'd like something like it, but starting from 0.

```
 command | cat -b
```

output:

> 1 This is string 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### I need to number lines starting from 0

Use `nl` instead of `cat`.

You can set the starting line number by using the `-v` option followed by the number you wish to start with:

```
command | nl -v 0
```

> `-v NUMBER`
>
> `--starting-line-number=NUMBER`
>
> ```
>  Set the initial line number on each logical page to `NUMBER`
>  (default 1).
> ```

Source [nl Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/nl.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Linux command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/)
- [nl Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/nl.html)
- [Linux nl Command Usage and Examples - Putorius](https://www.putorius.net/nl-command-basic-usage.html#changing-the-starting-line-number)